# Regex to end match after four sets of initials

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression with a variant that is used in javascript code to find words together as follows:

```
var re = new RegExp(firstWord+"\\s\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2,4}\\s\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+){1,8}\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})");
```

result with a match is as :

0 17.07.17 APPROVED FOR CONSTRUCTION SB SB GM TW ***DA MEA,GM,TW,DA,MEA***

The regex matches but includes extra characters at the end. In this example it is DA MEA,GM,TW,DA,MEA

Can anyone please advise how to modify the regex to end the match after the four sets of initials?

Comment: your desired output is GM,TW,DA,MEA ?

Comment: Hi Idle001, I need to exclude all words after the four sets of initials which would mean that DA MEA,GM,TW,DA,MEA is not required. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that would match and capture **DA MEA,GM,TW,DA,MEA** from the input:

> 0 17.07.17 APPROVED FOR CONSTRUCTION SB SB GM TW DA MEA,GM,TW,DA,MEA

```
\d\s\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s(?:.*?)(?:\s[a-zA-z]{2}){4}\s(.*)
```

**EDIT**

From what I understand what you actually want to match is the first part, here is a modified version of the regex to ignore the last part of the string.

```
\d\s\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s(?:.*?)(?:\s[a-zA-z]{2}){4}
```

This will match

```
0 17.07.17 APPROVED FOR CONSTRUCTION SB SB GM TW
```

Comment: Hi Alex, regex is not working, is including all words after the four sets of initials, please advise how to modify regex to end match after the initials, thank you for your help.

Comment: @JoJo based on your comment I added an other regex

Comment: thank you very much for your help with the regex, it is now working and ends the match after the 4 sets of initials.